# Starting out with Zend framework 2, class not found errors

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get started with a simple LAMP site however can't seem to get the Zend framework to be picked up by my local Apache instance. I started on XAMPP on Windows and have since tried a Centos 6 VM with manual Apache/PHP install, but still get the same error on both which is below. The phpinfo() works fine, as does the rest of the site.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Log\Logger' not found in /var/www/html/site/public/test.php on line 20
```

My website code is a fairly simple test to invoke a Zend framework logger which is as follows

```
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer;
echo "<p>Hello world</p>";
echo $_POST["VIN"]; 
phpinfo();
$logger = new Zend\Log\Logger;
$writter = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
$logger->addWriter($writer);
?>
```

My Apache linux httpd.conf is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site/public
<Directory /var/www/html/site/public>              
    DirectoryIndex test.php 
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My Zend framework resides in /var/www/html/site/library/Zend, and I've added /var/www/html/site/library to the php.ini include as well.

Comment: You need to add the Zend Library Path to your PHP Include path or implement some sort of Autoloader that loads the files from a specified path.

Comment: include_path .:/php/includes:/var/www/html/site/library is currently set

Comment: did you enable the autoloader?

Comment: Thanks Sam and Gordon, the missing autoloader it was, sadly there is no mention of that at all in http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else hitting this error you need to utilise an autoloader, something that's not mentioned on the Zend framework getting started wiki.

```
<?php 
use Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader;
use Zend\Log\Logger;
use Zend\Log\Writer;
require_once dirname((__DIR__)).'\library\Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();


echo "<p>Hello world</p>";
echo $_POST["VIN"]; 
phpinfo();

$logger = new Zend\Log\Logger;
$writer = new Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
$logger->addWriter($writer);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you includes a wrong path into the *include_path*, include `/var/www/html/site/Library` not `/var/www/html/site/Library/Zend`.

Check:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Or paste here your php.ini configuration or the phpinfo() response.

Comment: Have edited the question for clarity, the include_path currently sets .:/php/includes:/var/www/html/site/library

Comment: Ok, make sure the case is correct (Library o library) and then try to do what @LJT saids:

Comment: Ok, make sure the case is correct (Library o library) and then try to do what @LJT saids: 

    require_once 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php';

Or use something like Composer (http://getcomposer.org) or create your autoload PSR-0-compliant function

Answer (score 0):

The autoloader is indeed what is needed. If you've got the path to your library included in your php.ini, you can add the following code to get Zend to work as intended:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();
```